# First and second order derivation of multi-dimensional function

Tags: matrices, analysis, numerical-methods

My professor told me to implement `Newtons Method` to find the minimum of this function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx + b^Tx$$

given

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0.78 & -0.02 & -0.12 & -0.14\\-0.02 & 0.86 & -0.04 & 0.06\\-0.12 & -0.04 & 0.72 & -0.08\\-0.14 & 0.06 & -0.08 & 0.74\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$b = \begin{bmatrix}-0.76\\-0.08\\-1.12\\-0.68 \end{bmatrix}$$

`Newtons Method` requires analytical first ($\nabla f$) and second order ($H_f$) derivative. How am I supposed to calculate these of a 4-th dimensional function (without going crazy while doing it by hand)?

Edit: Writing everything down by hand, I get

$$f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = 0.39\cdot x_1^2 + 0.43\cdot x_2^2 + 0.36\cdot x_3^2 + 0.37\cdot x_4^2 - 0.02x_1x_2 - 0.12x_1x_3 - 0.14x_1x_4 + 0.06x_2x_4 - 0.08x_3x_4 - 0.04x_2x_3 - 0.76x_1 - 0.08x_2 - 1.12x_3 - 0.68x_4$$

and

$$\nabla f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \begin{bmatrix}0.78x_1 - 0.02x_2 - 0.12x_3 - 0.14x_4 - 0.76\\0.86x_2 - 0.02x_1 - 0.04x_3 + 0.06x_4 - 0.08\\0.72x_3 - 0.12x_1 - 0.08x_4 - 0.04x_2 - 1.12\\0.74x_4 - 0.14x_1 + 0.06x_2 - 0.08x_3 -0.68 \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$H_f = \begin{bmatrix}0.78 & -0.02 & -0.12 & -0.14\\-0.02 & 0.86 & -0.04 & 0.06\\-0.12 & -0.04 & 0.72 & -0.08\\-0.14 & 0.06 & -0.08 & 0.74\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: If you expand $f(x)$, you’ll find that it involves at most second-degree terms in the individual variables. Surely you can handle computing partial derivatives of that? In fact, $\nabla f$ has a rather simple expression in terms of $A$ and $b$.

Comment: @amd It just took me 15mins to write everything down by hand, and indeed, only second-degree terms. Nevertheless, so many addition / multiplication - if you might give me the `rather simple expression` I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Since you’re gone to all that trouble, you may as well differentiate what you’ve got and see if you can spot the patterns. That’s much easier to do if you use abstract $a_{ij}$ for the elements of $A$ instead of cluttering things up with actual numbers.

Comment: Just edited my initial post @amd

Comment: Have you noticed that $H_f=A$?

Comment: @amd I did, indeed :D